# Selecting the button pressed using IF statement PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I built a website with Wordpress ... this is the [link](http://dgprint.dg-site.com/)

I have this code

```
<p class="test"> 
<?php $button_value = get_field('button_name'); 

if($button_value==0) 
{ 
echo '<a href="?page_id=26" class="get_quote">get quote</a> '; 
}else if($button_value==1) 
{
echo 'message '; 
}
?> 
</p>
```

IF   `($button_value==0)` button displays...IF button `($button_value==1)` not displayed message.I do not understand why.

I use Custom Fields plugin.

Can you tell me please how to solve this problem?

Comment: try to add print_r($button_value); before the condition, to see, what you have inside tha variable

Comment: Debug the code and you will understand a little more... and we too.

Comment: Use `var_dump($button_value)` to see what is contained there.

Comment: try var_dump($button_value) or change line 7 to }elseif($button_value=='1')

Comment: it can be some type error. try intval($button_value) == 1

Comment: I added at the beginning condition print_r ($ button value); but nothing is printed on site ... so the value is null?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Advanced custom fields**, then try to use the number field instead of the text field. Or a better way would be to use a **boolean** value (like a check box). So when its pressed it will have a value Else it will be empty.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/

```
<?php $button_value = get_field('button_name'); 
if( get_field('button_name') ) { 
  // Value is True
}else{
  // Value is false
}
```

If you are using a text field then anything inside it will considered as string. Which means you are comparing a string against a number. in this case you will have to convert the type of variable into integer. Something like this

```
$button_value = (int)get_field('button_name');
```